How to get power bi visual level data using python code
I have a power bi report which is hosted on on-premises reporting server. Now I want to retrieve visual level data using python code. For example i have a card visual which is showing as "100" and this "100" is calculated based on measure, for some visuals the value is coming directly directly coming from column value in the dataset.
Now I want to retrieve measure value which is "100" and also i need the value which is coming directly from a column from python code. Is this possible? If yes, Kindly suggest further.

Hi Experts, Any updates.
